Proving an inequality: $\frac{(1+a^2)(1+b^2)(1+c^2)}{(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)} \ge \frac{1+abc}{2}$
The question is as follows:
Let $a, b, c \ge 0$. Prove that
$$\frac{(1+a^2)(1+b^2)(1+c^2)}{(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)} \ge \frac{1+abc}{2}$$
I started as follows:
(1) Proving for one variable- $a$
$$\frac{1+a^2}{1+a} \ge \frac{1+a}{2}$$
By Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality,
$$(1^2+a^2)(1^2 + 1^2) \ge (1\times1 + 1\times a)^2$$
$$\implies (1^2+a^2)(1^2 + 1^2) \ge (1+a)^2$$
$$\implies 2(1+a^2) \ge (1+a)^2$$
$$\implies \frac{(1+a^2)}{(1+a)} \ge \frac{(1+a)}{2} \blacksquare$$
(2) Proving for two variables- $a, b$
$$\frac{(1+a^2)(1+b^2)}{(1+a)(1+b)} \ge \frac{1+ab}{2}$$
By Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality,
$$(1^2 + a^2)(1^2 + b^2) \ge (1 \times 1 + a \times b)^2$$
$$\implies (1+a^2)(1+b^2) \ge (1+ab)^2$$
Assume that $(1+ab) \ge \frac{(1+a)(1+b)}{2}$
$$\therefore (1+a^2)(1+b^2) \ge \frac{(1+ab)(1+a)(1+b)}{2}$$
$$\implies \frac{(1+a^2)(1+b^2)}{(1+a)(1+b)} \ge \frac{1+ab}{2} \blacksquare$$
Now, assume $(1+ab) \le \frac{(1+a)(1+b)}{2}$
Now, from case 1, $\frac{1+a^2}{1+a} \ge \frac{1+a}{2}$ and $\frac{1+b^2}{1+b} \ge \frac{1+b}{2}$
Combining them, we get
$$\frac{(1+a^2)(1+b^2)}{(1+a)(1+b)} \ge \frac{(1+a)(1+b)}{2} \times \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\implies \frac{(1+a^2)(1+b^2)}{(1+a)(1+b)} \ge \frac{(1+ab)}{2} \blacksquare$$
(3) Proving for three variables- $a, b, c$
And here is where I get stuck with my current method. I am unable to proceed forward with this question. Any help will be extremely appreciated. If you have any other methods that involve common inequalities, that would be very much appreciated too. Thanks in advance!

Have you considered cross multiplying and rearranging to make the RHS zero? Sometimes, proving something is positive is not too difficult and then some rearrangement gives the required inequality. In this case since a,b,c are non-negative you do not need to worry about the direction of the inequality sign.

@RedFive I did! That was my first thought when I saw it, but nothing clicked afterwards.

Check https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h366242p5296159. The method extends to as many variables as you like.

@Macavity Ah, thank you very much for the help! I'll definitely check that out!

I've played around with the AM-GM inequality a bit using the result $2\sqrt{a} \leq a+1$ and this seems to go somewhere, just not far enough to be a postable answer (yet).

OK... see if this makes sense (and is error free...)
$2(1+x^{2})^{3}=(1+x)^{3}(1+x^{3})+(1-x^{3})(1-x)^{3}$
Now either $x\geq 1$ or $x<1$. In both cases, $(1-x^{3})(1-x)^{3}>0$
So $2(1+x^{2})^{3}\geq (1+x^{3})(1+x)^{3}$
So $2^{\frac{1}{3}} \times \frac{1+x^{2}}{1+x} \geq (1+x^{3})^{\frac{1}{3}}$
Letting $x=a$, $x=b$ and $x=c$ and multiplying the results together:
$\frac{2(1+a^{2})(1+b^{2})(1+c^{2})}{(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)}\geq[(1+a^{3})(1+b^{3})(1+c^{3})]^{\frac{1}{3}}$
Now $(1+a^{3})(1+b^{3})(1+c^{3})=(1+a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}+(ab)^{3}+(bc)^{3}+(ac)^{3}+(abc)^{3})$
By the AM-GM inequality, this is $\geq(1+3abc+3(abc)^{2}+(abc)^{3})=(1+abc)^{3}$
So $\frac{2(1+a^{2})(1+b^{2})(1+c^{2})}{(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)} \geq 1+abc$
And the result follows.
Edit just in case it is not obvious: equality holds if and only if $a=b=c=1$

Ok, this does make sense! But a question: The first step-
2(1+x2)^3=(1+x)^3(1+x^3)+(1−x^3)(1−x)^3
Was this pure intuition or was it somehow derived from the question itself?
And will this answer suffice for the entire question or do I need to showcase your answer with my one?

And thank you very much for your answer, it really helps!

I basically worked backwards. It took a lot of false starts...

Ok! Thank you very much

I found a similar looking question (but in less variables/parameters) than this on AOPS and it referenced something called Holder's inequality. I did some looking but cannot see if/how this would make the solution any easier. You may have a different experience.
